# Dictionary key assignment row wise

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I have Dictionary objects Dic1,Dic2, whose Items are an alphabet. Say

```
     Dic1(10)= A
     Dic1(111)= B
     Dic1(12)= C like this.


     Dic2(125)= A
     Dic2(131)= B
     Dic2(126)= C like this.
```

Now I am trying to assign their keys through a loop in Excel row(3rd column onwards) by below,but not all keys are getting copied.

```
    objSheet2.Range("C"&nRow).Value=Dic1.Keys() Or(condition wise any of the assignment
    will be executed)

    objSheet2.Range("C"&nRow).Value=Dic2.Keys()
```

But only the first Key value is getting copied,ignoring the other. Can you tell what the Bug is in my code?

**Edit**

```
Option Explicit

Class cP
 Public m_sRel
 Public m_dicC
    Private Sub Class_Initialize()
     m_sRel     = "Child"
     Set m_dicC = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    End Sub

    Public Function show()
     show = m_sRel & " " & Join(m_dicC.Keys)
    End Function

End Class

Dim objSheet1,objSheet2,TotalRows,TotalcolCopy,strPathExcel1
'Dim oFS   : Set oFS  = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim oXls  : Set oXls = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
'Dim aData ': aData    = oWb.Worksheets(1).Range("$A2:$C10")
Dim dicP  : Set dicP = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim nRow,nP,sKeys

strPathExcel1 = "D:\WIPData\AravoMacro\Finalscripts\A.xlsx"
oXls.Workbooks.open strPathExcel1
'oXls.Workbooks.Open(oFs.GetAbsolutePathName("A.xlsx"))
Set objSheet1 = oXls.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("WingToWingMay25")
Set objSheet2 = oXls.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ParentChildLink")


TotalRows=oXls.Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(objSheet1.Columns(1))
TotalcolCopy=oXls.Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Parent Business Process ID", objSheet1.Rows(3), 0)

objSheet1.Range(objSheet1.Cells(4,1),objSheet1.Cells(TotalRows,TotalcolCopy)).Copy(objSheet2.Range("A1"))
objSheet2.Range(objSheet2.Cells(1,2),objSheet2.Cells(TotalRows,TotalcolCopy-1)).Delete(-4159)
'Dim aData : aData=objSheet2.Cells.SpecialCells(12)'xlCellTypeVisible

Dim aData : aData = objSheet2.Range("A1:B"&TotalRows-3)

'MsgBox(LBound(aData, 1)&"And"&UBound(aData, 1))

   For nRow = LBound(aData, 1) To UBound(aData, 1)

     Set dicP(aData(nRow, 1)) = New cP
     'Set dicP(aData(nRow, 2)) = New cP

   Next
    'objSheet2.Cells.ClearContents'To clear all the previous contenets of the sheet#2
    'sKeys=dicP.Keys
    'objSheet2.Range("A1").Resize(dicP.Count) = oXls.Application.Transpose(sKeys) 
    'MsgBox(dicP.Count&":"&UBound(aData, 1)&":"&LBound(aData, 1))
    For nRow = LBound(aData, 1) To UBound(aData, 1)

        If aData(nRow, 1) = aData(nRow, 2) Then
           dicP(aData(nRow, 1)).m_sRel = "Parent"
        Else
            If dicP.Exists(aData(nRow, 2)) Then

            dicP(aData(nRow, 2)).m_dicC.Add   aData(nRow, 1), 0        '(aData(nRow, 1)) = 0

            End If
        End If

    Next

    objSheet2.Cells.ClearContents'To clear all the previous contenets of the sheet#2

    nRow=1
    For Each nP In dicP.Keys()

    objSheet2.Cells(nRow,1).Value=nP
    objSheet2.Cells(nRow,2).Value=dicP(nP).m_sRel
    objSheet2.Range("C"&nRow).Resize(1+ UBound(dicP(nP).m_dicC.Keys()) + 1).Value=dicP(nP).m_dicC.Keys()
    'Range("C" & nRow).Resize(1, UBound(d.Keys()) + 1).Value = d.Keys()
    nRow=nRow+1  
    Next
```

I am getting an error as `Unknown Run time error` at the line `objSheet2.Range("C"&nRow).Resize(1+ UBound(dicP(nP).m_dicC.Keys()) + 1).Value=dicP(nP).m_dicC.Keys()`

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you assign an array only to one cell. Then only the first value is copied in.
You have to assign the array to a range of the right size. This can be done with `Range.Resize`.
Then again, Excel treats the array as a 2-dimensional array (a matrix), and if it is only one-dimensional, this will always be the seen as the first row. If you copy this into a vertical range, each cell will have the same first element of your array.
For a vertical range, you have to transpose your array/virtual matrix:

```
Sub test()
    Dim d
    Dim nRow As Long

    nRow = 3
    Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    d(1) = "A"
    d(2) = "B"
    d(17) = "C"
    d(32) = "F"

    ' horizontal:
    Range("C" & nRow).Resize(1, UBound(d.Keys()) + 1).Value = d.Keys()

    ' vertical insert needs the data transformed
    Range("C" & nRow).Resize(UBound(d.Keys()) + 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(d.Keys())

End Sub
```

For your edit, you may first of all need to correct `("C"&nRow)` to `("C" & nRow)`. The spaces are required.
Another error is `Resize(1 + ... + 1)`, so you add +2, but this should not throw an error.

Comment: please dimension your variables completely. So 

`Dim d AS NEW Collection`
`Dim nRow AS Long`

Comment: @K_B You are exactly right,but what I think it is perfect for VBScript, As VBScript doesn't allow such dimensions. Before I applied the same and got errors for that,thus telling.

Comment: d is not a collection. It is assigned via late binding as thusly I keep it a Variant without explicit declaration.

Comment: @TukaiRakshit Ok thanks for informing me. Does the answer answer your question?

Comment: @KekuSemau what the systax `Resize(1, UBound(d.Keys())` stands for here? just making my concept clear. Would you please tell that?

Comment: Sure: As an example `Range("A1").Resize(3, 4)` would return a range object starting from A1, then resized to 3 rows and 4 columns, which equals A1:D3. You can omit parameters to leave them unchanged. `Range("A1").Resize(3)` returns `Range("A1:A3")`, `Range("A1").Resize(, 3)` returns the same as `Range("A1:C1")`

Comment: @KekuSemau see my **EDIT**. I am getting an error for the line mentioned in the description here.

Comment: I have added some lines to my answer as well.

Comment: @KekuSemau what you said I just did that,still I am getting the same error.

Comment: My bad: You can also use `dict.Count` instead of `Ubound(dict.Keys()) + 1`. For the error, I don't see it within the line. Try to msgbox something about that dictionary within the class object for debugging (one line above the error) to see if that's there and accessible in each loop.

Comment: @KekuSemau You are very close to the error,here for some dictionary has no keys thus an error has been thrown up,Now i fixed it by adding lines `If dicP(nP).m_dicC.Count>0 then`  `objSheet2.Range("C" & nRow).Resize(1, UBound(dicP(nP).m_dicC.Keys()) + 1).Value=dicP(nP).m_dicC.Keys()`  `end if`

Comment: @KekuSemau you are awesome, want to be like you people! :-) :-)

Comment: Thanks! +1 goes back for your responses and efforts.